# Data-GPS-Draggable Not Displaying Properly -- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, draggable, droppable

I'm able to do a drag and drop between two tables in a single view, successfully. It displays data as it should every time except for the very first time you try to drag-and-drop after the page loads.

What kinds of pitfalls are there in AngularJS to cause this? I haven't been able to find a solution. Here is my code:

```
        function dropOnMch(dragEl, dropEl) {
        var dragScope = angular.element(dragEl).scope();
        var dropScope = angular.element(dropEl).scope();

        if (dragScope.planDesign) {
            var mchPlan = {
                CustomerNumber: vm.customer.CustomerNumber,
                PlanCode: dragScope.planDesign.PlanCode,
                ContractNumber: dragScope.planDesign.ContractNumber,
                PlanEffectiveDate: new moment().add('m', 1).startOf('month'),
                PlanStatusDate: new moment().add('m', 1).startOf('month'),
                ChangeEffectiveDate: vm.changeEffectiveDate,
                PlanStatus: 'A'
            }

            var mch2 = replicatedDataService.createEntity('Mch2', mchPlan)
            vm.mchPlans.push(mch2);
        }          

        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

Here is my HTML table:

```
        <table class="table " data-gps-droppable="vm.dropOnMch(dragEl, dropEl)">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Customer Number</th>
                <th>PlanCode</th>
                <th>Contract Number</th>
                <th>Plan Effective Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Status Date</th>
                <th>Trust Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="plan in vm.mchPlans">
            <td><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="vm.remove(plan)"></i></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="plan.CustomerNumber"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="plan.PlanCode" />          </td>
            <td><span ng-bind="plan.ContractNumber" />    </td>
            <td><input type="date" ng-model="plan.PlanEffectiveDate" z-validate /> </td>
            <td><select ng-model="plan.PlanStatus" ng-options="status for status in vm.planStatuses" z-validate />        </td>
            <td><input type="date" ng-model="plan.PlanStatusDate" z-validate />    </td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="plan.TrustNumber" z-validate />       </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="99">Drop Plans Here to add them.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to put a metadata store fetch callback before doing any push operations

```
 var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("api/breeze");

function fetchMetadata() {

    if (manager.metadataStore.isEmpty()) {
        return manager.fetchMetadata();
    }

    return Q.resolve();
}
```